# Searching for an integer value in a varchar field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, integer, varchar

I have a table named `user` like below:

```
id || email
---------------------------------
1  || someone@foo.bar
---------------------------------
2  || 1manwithblueshirt@bar.foo
---------------------------------
```

Why is this:

```
1manwithblueshirt@bar.foo
```

result of this search?

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 1
```

Comment: It should result in `NULL`, imo.

Comment: but result is the email starts with "1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because MySQL decides to convert the email to an integer.  The rules are to convert leading characters to a number, until the characters are not valid numbers.

Here is a simple example:

```
select (case when '1abc' = 1 then 'a' else 'b' end)
```

Comment: @raminious . . . Because the SQL standard has not historically been very good at saying how these things work.  In other databases, trying to convert `'1abc'` to an integer would generate an error.  MySQL does not do that.

Comment: @raminious Perhaps if it is unexpected. This is, however, the behavior of Perl (and awk, if I recall), and it doesn't seem to cause Perl diehards much heartache.